# Backand deleteFile response ok but not actually deleting file (angular2)

Tags: angular, delete-file, backand

Hi so my issue is that I am uploading images fine to backand, I can view them in my app, see them on the server.

The problem comes when I try to delete the file, I am double checking that the name matches exact e.g. myimagetodelete.jpg

Here is the code...

```
    public deleteFile(objectName: string, fileActionName: string, filename: string) {
    // objectName: items
    // fileActionName: files
    let headers = this.authHeader;

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
    return this.http.delete(
        this.api_url + "/1/objects/action/" +  objectName + '?name=' + fileActionName + "&filename=" + filename,
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    );   

}
```

Everywhere I have looked has similar if nto identical code so I cannot work out why this would not work unless it is a problem with backand?

My "items" object files function in backand dashboard is like below incase needed.

```
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {
// upload file
if (request.method == "POST"){
    var url = files.upload(parameters.filename, parameters.filedata);
    return {"url": url};
}
// delete file
else if (request.method == "DELETE"){
    files.delete(parameters.filename);
    return {};    
}
```

}

Above code is pretty much "out the box" from backand.

Any help grately appreciated going nuts on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Backand. We use caching in AWS to provide some performance improvements in our S3 file storage solution. This is the likely source of your frustration - we've done some internal testing, and the cache can take up to an hour to update its contents, meaning that while the file itself has been deleted, the file may still be available for a period of time after that deletion.

To verify that the file was deleted, you can access your storage settings in Backand App Dashboard -> Hosting -> Storage Files, and refresh the list given. This should tell you whether or not the file was actually deleted. In my own testing, I verified the addition and removal of very simple file names and saw no issues in uploading or removing the file, so odds are you just were caught on the long end of cache expiration.

We'll be updating our documentation to account for this, and we apologize for the frustration you've experienced as a result.

There is one other thing that could cause this behavior, but it is not related to your use case - this is for general information for anyone coming in from the web. If you have modified your file storage action to do more complex manipulation of the filename that has uploaded, it is possible that this is what is causing your problem. Make sure that the code in your file action works correctly, and that the deletion accounts for any programmatic changes to the file name.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the response, since your response and logging into backand, all my images are no longer there and Errors are appearing in toast notifications with backand website.

I havnt touched any code since posting this and now the images wont upload, has anyone changed anything whilst looking into this issue under my account?

Comment: No, no one has changed anything in your account. This was likely due to the global AWS outage that took place. Can you check again and see if the issue persists?

Comment: I have double checked and it has been a good few days but the images are still showing in backand - is there a 30 day cache in aws or should they be gone by now?

Could there be an issue with the boilerplate code provided in the backand storage addon?

I am using this url...

https://api.backand.com/1/objects/action/items?name=files&filename=*************_1_wmdwm52n8u.jpg

I am also sending through the authentication headers as per all the other working api calls, I have tried postman and get a 200 success response, alas I am still seeing the images in backand.

Comment: Hi C.K. Munn - my apologies for the issue you are still experiencing! Can you contact us via the form at https://www.backand.com/contact/ so that we can provide more specific support? It seems like there may be either a bug in either your app's action or in our code, and we'll need to troubleshoot more in depth to find out which one is at fault.